# How to slim a jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I'm a happy user of the [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) library. Have been using it for years. The library weighs in at about 18 MB (yes, I kid you not)

I've always used [autojar](http://autojar.sourceforge.net/) to slim down the jar to only include the classes I actually need. This way I go from 18 MB to 250 KB.

Now this strategy doesn't work any more as autojar fails on Java 8 code. (possibly because the version of Apache BCEL that it uses is just too old)

Anyway, more generally, how does one slim a jar file?  I'll be happy to use any type of tool or library for the purpose, it just has to understand Java 8 bytecode.

Comment: Why bother?  Disk is cheap.  I package those fatties and sleep well at night.  This is a waste of time and unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @duffymo. You may just be right that this is a concern from a distant past. :-)

Comment: Hard to understand why it's part of your present.  Even a Raspberry Pi can have a glut of storage: https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/8/31/16232618/sandisk-400gb-microsd-card-worlds-largest-ever-storage

Comment: AWS Lambdas have a size constraint of 250mb so there is one very present challenge